# Looking for a paper by Vizing (1976) introducing the list chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

I am studying about the [list chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) in graph theory, and Vizing (1976) and Erdős–Rubin–Taylor (1979) are credited for independently introducing this concept.

I was able to locate the 1979 paper, but I'm unable to find the 1976 paper anywhere online. I have seen it cited variously as:

- V. G. Vizing, *Färbung der Ecken eines Graphen mit vorgeschriebenen Farben*,
  Metody Diskretn. Anal. **29** (1976), 3–10 (Russian). [Zbl 0362.05060](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0362.05060)
- V. G. Vizing, *Färbung der Ecken eines Graphen mit vorgeschriebenen Farben*, Diskret. Analiz, Novosibirsk **29** (1976), 3–10 (Russian).
- V. G. Vizing, *Coloring the vertices of a graph in prescribed colors*, Diskret. Analiz **29** Metody Diskret. Anal. v Teorii Kodov i Shem (1976), 3–10, 101 (Russian). [MR0498216](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0498216)

and with a few other variations too.

Does anyone know if this paper is available somewhere that can be (easily) accessed?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, the citation in the (original?) Russian is "Визинг В. Г., Раскраска вершин графа в предписанные цвета // Дискретный анализ. — 1976. — Т. 29. — С. 3—10." as cited on Wikipedia. This is possibly the same issue that's called "Методы дискретного анализа в теории кодов и схем" [here](http://new.math.msu.su/department/dm/dmmc/PUBL/DA.htm). But none of this got me any closer to the paper itself :(

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for taking a look! It does seem that the paper is difficult to locate online :(

Comment: Have you tried Interlibrary Loan via your local public or university library?

Comment: @bof I've never tried that before! I'll find out now if my library has such a facility.

Comment: @bof Unfortunately, my library was unsuccessful in procuring the paper. Just thought I should let you know. Ah well!

Comment: Similar question asked at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) (but without any success there either): [A copy of the Vizing's classic article about List Coloring.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/110123)

Comment: I was able to acquire a copy of the article from the British Library: I've added details in an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429801) on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet an easy access, but I've found several restricted ones. I'm adding them in case you have specific access.

I started from another [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X(00)00377-2) of Vizing, "On connected list colorings of graphs", where he cites himself as:

> V.G. Vizing, *Vertex coloring of a graph with assigned colors*, Metody Diskret. Analiz. (Novosibirsk) **29** (1976) 3–10 (in Russian)

I tried to locate the journal rather than the article. I found a [Google Books](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=PDm7AAAAIAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions) reference, but without access (or at least I couldn't find how). However the article seems to have been uploaded by UCLA. So I went to their website: they do have it on paper and [online](https://search.library.ucla.edu/permalink/01UCS_LAL/17p22dp/alma9913318087506531), but the online access requires a UCLA authorization. If you go straight to the [HathiTrust Digital library](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/006181412), they also say that the access is restricted to UCLA.

I also found a hard copy in some US libraries ([Alberta University](https://www.library.ualberta.ca/permalink/opac/2293130/WUAARCHIVE), [Kansas City](https://catalog.lindahall.org/permalink/01LINDAHALL_INST/19lda7s/alma991645783405961), [University of Michigan](https://search.lib.umich.edu/catalog/record/990005348180106381)).

Depending on your location, your local university might be the safest bet.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I didn't come across the Google Book link, nor the HathiTrust Digital Library one in my searches. Perhaps I'll be able to point out these resources to my local university library and see if they can help me the rest of the way. :)

Comment: Good Luck then! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my library was unsuccessful in procuring the paper. Just thought I should let you know, since you helped me out so nicely. Ah well!

Comment: Thanks for the update. shame!

Comment: I tried to acquire the article from the Kansas City library's [document delivery service](https://www.lindahall.org/document-delivery/). They responded that they don't own the particular volume (no. 29) which contains Vizing's article. Just thought I should mention it here, in case it helps others...